# How can I remove formatting from style numbering prefix in MSWord?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles, text-formatting

There is a lame user [in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKeJIYCtcMU) cannot remove bold+uppercase from the numbering prefix in his heading style. What is his mistake? How can one do that?

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to use numbering in the context context menu rather than style editor and update the style using this menu

[image]

In the end, you will get desired

[image]